# Bounded variant generic becomes Any?

Tags: scala, generics, variance, type-bounds

I was tinkering with some generics, laziness, and implicits and hit a wall that I'm pretty sure is related only to the bounding of my generic types (but I might be wrong...) I was attempting to build a Stream-Like thing:

```
object MyStream {
  def empty = new MyStream[Nothing] {
    def isEmpty = true
    def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("tead of empty MyStream")
    def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of empty MyStream")
  }

  def cons[T, U >: T](h: U, t: => MyStream[T]): MyStream[U] = new MyStream[U] {
    def isEmpty = false
    def head = h
    lazy val tail = t
  }

  implicit class MyStreamOps[T](t: => MyStream[T]) {
    def #:: [U >: T](h: U): MyStream[U] =
      cons(h, t)
  }
}

abstract class MyStream[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: MyStream[T]
  @tailrec final def foreach(op: T => Unit): Unit = {
    if (!isEmpty) {
      op(head)
      tail.foreach(op)
    }
  }
}
```

It actually seems to work pretty well, except for one thing, (at least as far as my tests have gone, so I might be missing other problems). That one thing is that with the bounds I've used in the cons and #:: behaviors, every MyStream degenerates to a MyStream[Any].

However, if I go with naive generics:

```
def cons[T](h: T, t: => MyStream[T]): MyStream[T] = new MyStream[T] ...
```

The types remain stable, but I can't use cons / #:: to attach anything to a MyStream.empty, because that's MyStream[Nothing], nor can I have any other variations in my types when using these operations (which, obviously rather breaks the thing).

I thought I was following fairly closely along with an example that Martin Odersky gives in the context of variance in List, and the only key difference here seems to be the "static" nature of my cons / #:: operations (which I *believe* are esssential as I don't think I can have a "lazy this" (conceptually, that seems impossible to me at least!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few points. First of all, the claim that

> That one thing is that with the bounds I've used in the cons and #:: behaviors, every MyStream degenerates to a MyStream[Any].

is actually not true. You can see it yourself at this [live demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Et0PBLxDRcOmQ1002xCXbw). Note how `ssGood` is easily assigned to a typed `ssGood2` without any need for cast and you can't do it with `ssBad` explicitly typed as `MyStream[Any]`. The point here is that Scala compiler gets the types quite right in this scenario. What I ***suspect*** that what you actually mean is that Intellij IDEA infers wrong types and does some bad highlighting etc. Unfortenately for techincal reasons IDEA uses its own compiler rather the standard one and sometimes gets things wrong when the code is complicated. Sometimes you actually have to compile the code to see if it is correct or not.

Second claim about naive generics also doesn't look correct to me.

> However, if I go with naive generics:

`def cons[T](h: T, t: => MyStream[T]): MyStream[T] = new MyStream[T] ...`

> The types remain stable, but I can't use cons / #:: to attach anything to a MyStream.empty ...

When I use the following code ([available online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tgvxCQZJTraDh7hjfOgVmQ))

```
object MyStream {
  val empty: MyStream[Nothing] = new MyStream[Nothing] {
    override def isEmpty = true

    override def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("tead of empty MyStream")

    override def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of empty MyStream")
  }

  def cons[T](h: T, t: => MyStream[T]): MyStream[T] = new MyStream[T] {
    def isEmpty = false

    def head = h

    lazy val tail = t
  }

  implicit class MyStreamOps[T](t: => MyStream[T]) {
    def #::(h: T): MyStream[T] = cons(h, t)
  }

}

abstract class MyStream[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean

  def head: T

  def tail: MyStream[T]

  @tailrec final def foreach(op: T => Unit): Unit = {
    if (!isEmpty) {
      op(head)
      tail.foreach(op)
    }
  }
}

import MyStream._

val ss0 = 1 #:: empty
val ss1: MyStream[Int] = ss0
val ss2: MyStream[Int] = 1 #:: empty
```

it compiles and runs OK for me as long as there is `[+T]` on
`MyStream[+T]` declaration. And this time I'm not sure what exactly you are doing wrong (and you didn't provide any actual compiler errors so it is hard to guess).

Also if your `empty` is non-generic and immutable, there is no need for it to be `def` - it could be `val` as well.

If you still have some issues, you should probably provide more details on how to reproduce it and what error(s) you get.

---

**Update** (answer to comment)

Toby, sorry, I still don't understand your issue #2. Could you provide an example of the code that doesn't compile in your question or as a comment?

My only guess is that what you mean is that if you use the code with just one generic `T` as in the main answer, a piece of code like this fails:

```
def test() = {
  import MyStream._

  val ss0: MyStream[String] = "abc" #:: empty
  val sb = new StringBuilder
  val ss1: MyStream[CharSequence] = ss0                          //OK
  val ss2: MyStream[CharSequence] = cons(sb, ss0)                //OK
  val ss3: MyStream[CharSequence] = sb #:: ss0                   //Bad?
}
```

Yes, this is true because AFAIU the Scala compiler when checking for implicit wrappers doesn't try to go through all posible substitutes of all generic types and uses only the most specific one. So `ss0` is tried to be converted to `MyStreamOps[String]` but not to `MyStreamOps[CharSequence]`. To fix that issue you need to add another generic type `U >: T` to the `#::` in the `MyStreamOps` but don't have to add to the `cons`. So with the following `MyStream` definition

```
object MyStream {
  val empty: MyStream[Nothing] = new MyStream[Nothing] {
    override def isEmpty = true

    override def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("tead of empty MyStream")

    override def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of empty MyStream")
  }

  def cons[T](h: T, t: => MyStream[T]): MyStream[T] = new MyStream[T] {
    def isEmpty = false

    def head = h

    lazy val tail = t
  }

  implicit class MyStreamOps[T](t: => MyStream[T]) {
    //def #::(h: T): MyStream[T] = cons(h, t)  // bad
    def #::[U >: T](h: U): MyStream[U] = cons(h, t) //good
  }  
}
```

even the `ss3` compiles without errors (and `ss2` that uses `cons` compiles even without `U` exactly because `+T` works).

Comment: On point 1, fascinating. I'm unsure what the proper etiquette is in SO for this, but I'll add an "answer" to address this.

On point 2, I did indeed misspeak--I'd been fighting with two issues for a while, and the second had gotten lost in my mind. What breaks is not the use of empty, but it fails when I try to make a stream of "child" class, then prepend a "parent" class to it. One would expect that, since the +T part handles "stream of sub is assignable to stream of parent", but it's the U >: T bounds thing, and allowing #:: to return a stream of parent type that's needed in that case.

Comment: @TobyEggitt, sorry, I still don't understand your issue #2. Could you provide an example of the code that doesn't compile here or in your question? See more details in the update in my answer.

Comment: Well, I can't format it here, but consider this use:

    val p = new Parent("p")
    val c1 = new Child1("c1")

    val ps = p #:: MyStream.empty
    val pc1 = c1 #:: MyStream.empty
    val px = p #:: pc1 // This !

Comment: If that's too darn cryptic, LMK and I'll find some other way to put more complete code in there. That example, "prepending" a Parent to a Stream[Child] only works with the use of #:: [U >: T] ... constraints

Comment: @TobyEggitt, 1) Yes, code in comments doesn't look good. That's why I suggested editing the question if you need a lot of code (IMHO, your current example is small enough, also having separate code sections using **\`** (backquote) for each line might work as a substitute for format such as `val p = new Parent("p")` `val c1 = new Child1("c1")` ). 2) I'm not sure how your example is different from the one I described in my update (add both `String` and `StringBuilder`) with the reason why `[U >: T]` is required in this case. If something is still unclear to you I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: No, sorry, when I posted my reply, your "update" section didn't show up (I probably hadn't refreshed the window). You're exactly right in that; going with the commented-out, single generic type, declarations prevented the IntelliJ compiler from degenerating things to MyStream[Any] but obviously messes up the ability to "move up" the generalization hierarchy. The "proper" declarations worked just fine, except in so far as the bug in IntelliJ.

It's all totally clear to me, from the moment you prompted me to realize that it was IntelliJ and not my code. Really appreciate your taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that my first point above is perhaps a reflection of a bug in the IntelliJ compiler SergGr's answer above points out that he doesn't see the problem. And, sure enough, if I take my same code and compile it on the command line, it works perfectly. However, this is what IntelliJ shows me:

[image]

I've noticed already that the IntelliJ worksheet feature has some "issues" (on one occasion suggesting a refactoring that was syntactically wrong), but this is the first time I've seen it fail in the "real compiler" section.

FWIW, this is IntelliJ 2017.3.2 CE, and it seems to be running on Open JDK 1.8.0 (I didn't put that there--I'm using Java 9 for Java work), so I presume it's the IntelliJ bundled JVM) and Scala 2.11.6.